# Anypoint MQ - how can AWS Lambda subscribe for messages without connector

Tags: lambda, mulesoft, anypoint-mq

From my AWS Lambda I need to subscribe to messages in Anypoint MQ published by S4/Hana.
I want my Lambda to be invoked when a message is publised to the Anypoint MQ queue.
I understand there is a Mule Lambda connector. Since I do not have any control over Anypoint MQ, that would not be useful.

Please let me know if there is to invoke my Lambda function by Anypoint MQ thru an API Gateway or by any other method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean MuleSoft's Anypoint MQ (https://docs.mulesoft.com/mq/)? There is not MuleSoft MQ. Or do you mean Mule JMS connector connecting to some other message broker?

Comment: Yes I mean MuleSoft Anypoint MQ. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Anypoint MQ is a message broker that receives messages and delivers them to client applications. It can not trigger execution of anything else. It doesn't look

You need to create a client application that is capable of trigger the Lambda execution. You could do that using a separate Mule application which listens to Anypoint MQ messages with the Anypoint MQ connector and triggers Lambda execution using the Amazon Lambda Connector. This should be very simple to implement in Mule provided you are familiar with Mule.

Alternatively you can create a client application in any programming language that can interact with [Anypoint MQ REST API](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mq/mq-apis) to query messages and is also able to trigger Lambda. This option may require more effort.

Note that API Gateway is basically a feature of Mule runtime, so deploying the Mule application to a Mule runtime means the same than to deploy it to API Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way could be creating a new mule application that can subscribe from AMQ and send a HTTP call to Aws API gateway that is connected to AWS lambda.